# Designing XPages applications for large user populations and high performance

Tags: performance, xpages

The following questions were posed by a customer who is about to write a large scale XPages application. While I think the questions are actually to broad to fit stackoverflow style, they are interesting and the collective knowledge of the experts here could yield better results than one person answering them:

1. How many concurent users can use XPages applications on 1 Lotus Domino server (There are several applications on Lotus Domino server. Not one)?
2. How can we define and analyze memory leaks on Lotus Domino server, when run XPages application?
3. How can we write XPages the right way for achiving the best performance and avoding memory leaks?
4. What code methods and objects should not be used?
5. What are typical errors when the Lotus Script developer begins to write the code for XPages? What are the best practises?
6. How can we build centralized, consolidated application on XPages for 10000 - 15000 users? How many servers we need? How to configure XPages application in that case?
7. How to balace users?

I will provide my insights, please share yours

Comment: I want to suggest to split wide scope of your question to more question: topics 2+3, 1+6, 4+5, 7 for example.

Comment: I was considering that, since it makes sense. But then that was the blurb I got, so I kept it together (makes sense too from a customer perspective)

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662069/what-are-your-top-3-xpages-performance-tips-for-new-xpages-developers

Answer (score 2):

1. How long is a string? It depends on how the server is configured. And "application" could be a single form or hundreds. Only a test can tell. In general: build a [high performance server](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7RB3P5) preferably with 64Bit architecture and lots of RAM. Make that RAM [available for the JVM](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Memory_Usage_and_Performance). If the applications use attachments, use DAOS, put it on a separate disk  - and of course make sure you have the latest version of Domino (8.5.3FP1 at time of this writing)
2. There is the [XPages Toolbox](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=xpages%20toolbox) that includes a memory and CPU profiler.
3. It depends on the type of application. Clever use of the scopes for caching, Expression Language and beans instead of SSJS. You leak memory whey you forget `.recycle`. Hire an experienced lead developer and [read the book](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0132486318) also [the other one](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0132901811) and [two](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0132943050). Consider threading off longer running code, so users don't need to wait.
4. Depends on your needs. The general lessons of Domino development apply when it comes to db operations, so FTSearch over DBSearch, scope usage over @DBColumn for parameters. EL over SSJS.
5. Typical errors include: all code in the XPages -> use script libraries. Too much @dblookup, @dbcolumn instead of scope. Validation in buttons instead of validators. Violation of decomposition principles. Forgetting to use .recycle(). Designing applications "like old Notes screens" instead of single page interaction. Too little use of partial refresh. No use of caching. Too little object orientation (crating function graves in script libraries).
6. This is a summary of question 1-5, nothing new to answer
7. When clustering Domino servers for XPages and putting a load balancer in front, the load balancer needs to be configured to keep a session on the same server, so partial refreshes and Ajax calls reach the server that has the component tree rendered for that user.

Comment: ad 1. - there is internal limit of roughly 10k Notes objects. Divided equally to http threads it leads to 10k/threads - average number of notes objects in one thread. If we count with margin of tens for such objects per average XPage (thread), maximum number of concurrent users is just few hundreds to one thousand.

Comment: Frantisek I would be very interested if you could explain more about what you mean? 10k object per thread leads up to 100 - 1000 users?
What are these objects (XPage control, design element) ?

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on the server setup, I have i.e XPage extranet with 12000 registered users spanning over aprox 20 XPage applications. That runs on 1 Windows 2003 server with 4GB Ram and quad core cpu. Data aount is about 60GB over these 20 applications. No Daos, no beans just SSJS. Performance is excellent. So when I upgrade this installation to 64 bit and Daos the application will scale when more. So 64Bit and Lots of Ram is the key to alot of users.
2. I haven't done anything around this
3. Make sure to recyle when you do document loops, Use the openntf.org debug toolbar it will save alot of time before we have a debugger for XPages.
4. Always think when you are doing things this will be done by several users, so try to cut down number of lookup or getElementByKey. Try to use ViewNavigator when you can.
5. It all depends on how many users that uses the system concurrent. If you have 10000 - 15000 users concurrent then you have to look at what the applications does and how many users will use the same application at the same time.

Thats my insights into the question

Comment: Appreciate your contribution!